# Connecting networks by adding edge between same items in the networks

Tags: python-3.5, networkx

[image]I am studying cellular pathways and I wanted to know how could I use the networkx to show how networks which share same elements are connected.

```
 HH_signaling = ['GLI1', 'PTCH1', 'PTCH2', 'WNT5A', 'HHIP1', 'MYCN', 'CCND1', 'CCND2', 'BCL2', 'CFLAR', 'FOXF1', 'FOXL1', 'PRDM1', 'JAG2', 'GREM1']
    Wnt_signaling = ['GLI1', 'PTCH1', 'WNT5A', 'HHIP1', 'MYCN', 'CCND1','WNT7A','WNT2','CDK1','CK1']
    Proliferation_signaling = ['GLI1', 'CCNDA', 'BMP4', 'BMP7', 'MTOC2', 'CCND1']

    g = nx.Graph()
    def link_networks(N1, N2, N3, N4=None, N5=None, N6=None, N7=None, N8=None, N9=None):
        for i in N1:
            for i in N2:
                for i in N3:
                    g.add_edge(N1[i],N2[i],N3[i])

link_networks(HH_signaling, Wnt_signaling, Proliferation_signaling)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

networkx doesn't have the notion of a hyper node (nor does any other network analysis package that I know) so there is no simple way to recreate your drawing. There are also a few other technical limitations (nodes need to have different names (AFAIK)) that make the naive approach for the graph generation difficult.

To me it seems, that you are trying to re-invent the wheel. Don't you just want a Venn diagram showing the overlap between the different pathways? 
Something like:

[image]

Code:

```
import venn_wordcloud; reload(venn_wordcloud)

HH = ['GLI1', 'PTCH1', 'PTCH2', 'WNT5A', 'HHIP1', 'MYCN', 'CCND1', 'CCND2', 'BCL2', 'CFLAR', 'FOXF1', 'FOXL1', 'PRDM1', 'JAG2', 'GREM1']
Wnt = ['GLI1', 'PTCH1', 'WNT5A', 'HHIP1', 'MYCN', 'CCND1', 'WNT7A', 'WNT2', 'CDK1', 'CK1']
CC = ['GLI1', 'CCNDA', 'BMP4', 'BMP7', 'MTOC2', 'CCND1']

venn_wordcloud.venn3_wordcloud([set(HH), set(Wnt), set(CC)],
                               set_labels=['Hedgehog', 'Wnt', 'Cell Cycle'])
```

The code for venn_wordcloud is available on my github:
https://github.com/paulbrodersen/venn_wordcloud.

Apart from numpy and matplotlib (which you should have installed before installing networkx), it depends on matplotlib-venn and wordcloud, which can be installed via pip:

```
pip install matplotlib-venn wordcloud
```